# Can't extend abstract class that is from other package

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm building a library for javascript and typescript(for extends) with webpack and typescript. I want to make class extend other npm library's(that exports abstract class) abstract class, but when i run compiled code, it throws error.

> Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

It seems that the program tries to load abstract class in compiled(js) class on runtime.

My codes:

webpack config

```
const development = process.env.dev === "true" ? true : false;

console.log(development);

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: development ? "development" : "production",
    target: 'node',
    entry:{
        index:"./src/index.ts"
    },
    output:{
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          //exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [
    ],
    externals: [

    ]
};
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2017",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@src/*":["src/*"]
        },
        "lib": ["dom","es2017"]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/*",
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Compiler.ts

```js
import { Controller } from "npmLibraryName"; //Controller is abstract class

class Compiler extends Controller {
    init(){}
}

export default Compiler;
```

Comment: Make sure `npmLibraryName` doesn't export `Controller` as a default export.

Comment: I exported like this:

import Controller from "./Controller/";

export {
   Controller
}

Comment: You've used `"./Controller/"` is there an `index.js` file in the **Controller** folder, also, can you check if `Controller` is `undefined` in the `npmLibraryName` module ?

Comment: The only time I've observer this kind of thing (an `undefined` import) was when I had a *circular dependency*, in those cases, webpack will load the module async and it will be `undefined` for a short while.

Comment: I'm sorry. I solved this problem, but i can't know the reason why it working. I think it is related to webpack libraryTarget.  Thanks.

Comment: @coloud how did you solve the problem?